# LDAP Authentication always requires the domain as part of username

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I'm trying to authenticate a user using LDAP for Windows Server for AD authentication.  Below is my code:

```
 string domList = "LDAP://172.21.0.1:389/CN=Configuration,DC=myDom,DC=local;
 System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry deRoot = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(domList, userNameURL, password, authType);
                                    deRoot.RefreshCache();
```

This works fine in most cases, I have one particular site where I get an invalid username/password error.

If I change the username to be of the format myDom\username then it works.  However I only want the user to enter their username. I don't see why the domain is needed as it's part of the LDAP connection string.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a red herring.  I need to set the authentication type to be secure